# Using Hooke's Law to find the work required to stretch a spring.

Tags: calculus

Eighteen foot-pounds of work is required to stretch a spring 4 inches from its natural length. Find the work required to stretch the spring an additional 3 inches.

My attempts at this problem have led to a dead end. 
Here is one of the four that I have tried.

$$ 18=k(4) $$
$$k=\frac{18}{4}$$
Now I have,
$$ F(x)=\frac{18}{4}x$$
Because the spring is stretched from $x=4$ to $x=7$, the work done is 
$$W=\int_{4}^{7}\frac{18}{4}x dx$$
$$=110.25-36$$
$$W=74.25$$
This converted between foot-pounds and inch-pounds still yields the wrong answer. The correct answer is $37.125 \mathrm {foot-pounds}$.
Please, if anyone knows a correct way to achieve the answer using calculus and Hooke's law please respond.

Comment: Hint: What is the difference between your answer and the correct answer? It should be apparent.

Comment: @DisplayName The answer I got is 74.25. The true answer is 37.125

Comment: Refer to the answer by Eric. You will probably now notice $74.25$ is exactly $2*37.125$

Answer (score 3):

The error occurred when you used $18 = k(4)$, an incorrect assumption. Let's derive an equation relating the work needed.

We start with the definition of work:

$W = \int_a^bF_{spring}dx$

By Hooke's Law, we have:

$F_{spring} = kx$

So, to find the work needed, we have to evaluate the integral:

$W = \int_a^bF_{spring}dx = \int_a^bkxdx = \frac{1}{2}kx^2\mid_a^b$

Since $a = 0$,

$W_4  = 18= \frac{1}{2}k(4)^2$ and it turns out that $k = \frac{9}{4}$

Your value for $k$ is 2x the correct value, which explains why your answer is 2x the correct answer.

Comment: Wow, thank you @Eric. I didn't think of that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Everything above is correct except in the beginning you want to convert your bounds from inches to feet as follows:

- 4 inches = 1/3 feet
- 7 inches = 7/12 feet

I hope this helps